# Complexity analysis for finding all powers of 2 within a range

Tags: time-complexity

Suppose you're given $x,y$ integers s.t. $x \leq y$. I want to find all values $\in [x, y]$ (inclusive) that are a power of $2$.

There's a $O(\log y)$ approach, where you just start at $1$, and keeping multiplying by $2$ until you get to the first value that is $\geq x$. Then you can start storing these values until you get to a power of 2 that is $> y$.

There's another approach that I believe is $O( \log (\log b))$, but I am not certain.
The idea I am thinking of is rather than multiplying by $2$ each time, you square the value. So you'd have to start at $2$, then check $4$, then $16$, then $256$ and so on until you find the first value that is $>= x$. Say this value is $k$ where $k \geq x$.
I believe finding $k$ is $O(\log(\log b))$. Is that correct?

After finding $k$, you can keep dividing by $2$ until you get a value that is $< x$ and store all the values along the way (unless it's greater than $y$). Then you can do this in the upward direction and keep multiplying by $2$ until you get to a value that's greater than $y$. It's not clear to me what the complexity of this step is. I want to say it's $O(\log (\log b))$ as well, but it seems it may actually be $O(\log b)$.

Comment: Why not simply find formula and obtain $O(1)$ complexity?

Comment: @zkutch This is more of a complexity analysis question than "what's the best algorithm to solve this?" With that said, what's the formula?

Comment: Calculating amount by formula is also algorithm, not only finding it by loop. Using loop in such cases, when exists formula for answer is worst what can be done.

Comment: @zkutch I don't really see what this has to do with my question. I'm asking about the time complexity for my specific algorithm, not how to solve it in a different way.

Comment: I want only warn against a situation where using a loop is unreasonably expensive - you will not count the sum of numbers in a loop if/when you know the answer by the formula, right? the rest is, of course, your business and I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: @zkutch, I can't understand how your replies relate to the question or how they help with this problem.  I don't know what formula you have in mind or why you think there is a formula that solves this problem in $O(1)$ time.

Comment: @D.W. These are comments and not answers with the aim of being useful: if you see that someone is paying for free, then have you  the right to remain silent? To avoid long comments and if you are interested in formula, I suggest continuing the conversation in a some separate chat.

Comment: @zkutch, I apologize, but I don't understand what you are saying.  I don't know what you mean by "paying for free" or what you are referring to when you mention remaining silent.  If you know of a formula that can be computed in $O(1)$ time, I suggest showing it; if you don't know of such a formula, then I am not sure what the purpose of your comments is.  I apologize if my lack of understanding is due to communication difficulties.

Comment: @D.W.  Let me also apologize, if my English is so bad, that I have not clearly expressed my thoughts. Of course, I may be wrong, but I bring an idea: let's consider inequality $2^n \leqslant x, x\in \mathbb{R}$, and try to find maximal solution $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We have $n \leqslant \log_2 x$ and solution will be $n=\left\lfloor\log_2 x \right\rfloor$.  To find $n$ we need to calculate the integer part of the logarithm once. Do you agree with me up to this point?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct, in a sense, but there is also a sense in which it is not correct.

You want to find $j$ such that $2^j \in [x,y]$.  The naive algorithm uses linear search on $j$.  Your proposed algorithm amounts to binary search on $j$ (starting with iterative doubling).  So your analysis is correct, that it uses $O(\log \log y)$ iterations.

The shortcoming of your analysis is that you assume each iteration can be done in $O(1)$ time.  This might be accurate, or it might not, depending on the specific theoretical model of computation you are using.  In practice, it is probably not reasonable, if $x,y$ are very large, as the running time of each iteration is not $O(1)$.  For instance, squaring a $n$-bit number takes $O(n)$ time (in many reasonable ways of measuring running time); here we have $n=\lg y$, so each iteration takes $O(\log y)$ time, for a total running time of $O((\log y)(\log \log y))$ time (at least under one way of measuring running time).

Another way to put it is that it takes $O(\lg y)$ time even just to read the input or produce the desired output, because the output will be $\Omega(\lg y)$ bits long, and the time it takes to print such an output is proportional to its length.

Comment: That makes sense. I was assuming each iteration is in $O(1)$ time. How about the latter half of the question (after finding $k$)? Also note that my $k$ is different from yours. I defined $k$ to be the first value $\geq x$ after starting from $2$ and continuously squaring the value. To avoid mixing up variables, I'll use the variable $c$ to represent this value. To find $c$, and assuming $O(1)$ per iteration, you confirmed that it's $O(\log (\log(y))$. But we need to find all the powers of $2$ within the given range.

Comment: Even with $c$, it seems that have a to do a linear scan (over the exponents), and that linear scan would seem to be $O(\log y)$ (again assuming O(1) per iteration).

Comment: @anonuser01, oops, sorry about re-using the same variable.  I changed it to $j$.

Answer (score -1):

A simple algorithms is, start from $x$, and check whether it's power of $2$ or not, then increment one by one until you get $y$, this algorithm need $\mathcal{O}(y-x)$ steps, that each steps needs to read $\mathcal{O}(\log i)$ bits. Hence the running time is $$\sum_{i=x}^{y}\mathcal{O}(1+\log i)=\mathcal{O}\left(y-x+\log \left(\frac{y!}{(x-1)!}\right)\right)\leq\mathcal{O}((y-x)\log y)$$.

**So the lower bound for solving your problem is $\mathcal{\Omega}(\log y)$ .**

Note that, by using [Binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20binary%20search,middle%20element%20of%20the%20array.) idea, we can at each step increment the counter by a $2^{2^c}$ that reduce the running time to  $\mathcal{O}(\log y\log\log(y-x))$.